# Unable to configure json with spring - Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm not able to correctly configure json support with Spring 4.0.4. A json request results in:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(246):  - Looking up handler method for path /equipments/datatable.json
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(134):  - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.resolveException(134):  - Resolving exception from handler [null]:             org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(134):  - Resolving exception from handler [null]:      org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(198):  - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I have an `applicationContext.xml` and a `my-servlet.xml`:

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>                      
        /WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/conf/my-security.xml          
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>losap</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/my-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.htg.*">
   <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.htg\.myapp\.mvc"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="messageAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**my-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>        
<context:component-scan base-package="com.htg.myspp.mvc" />
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping(value = "/equipments")
public class EquipmentController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/datatable.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept:*/*", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Equipment getEquipmentsDatatable(Model model) {
        Equipment e = new Equipment();
        e.setEquipmentName("Lathe 123");
        e.setEquipmentNumber("12345TTY");
        e.setId(89L);
        return e;
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON($('#ctxtrelurl').val() + 'equipments/datatable.json', function(e) {
    console.log(e.equipmentName);
});
```

**Chrome Dev. Tools output**
[image]

I have a feeling it has something to do with having two separate context config. files. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any other function in your controller, that is supporting PUT request?

Comment: Can you verify on your application startup, the log would contain something like this "Mapped "{[/eqipments/datatable.json],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[Accept:*/*],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public  EquipmentController.getEquipmentsDatatable". Basically this would make sure that the mapping was correctly read by Spring

Comment: @JohnnyAW, yes i do: @RequestMapping(value = "/{equipId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)

Comment: @Shailendra, No I don't see it. I see all the rest, but not this one.

Comment: It simply means this was not picked up so it won't respond to your request.

Answer (score 0):

ok, my guess is, that spring doesn't map `/datatable.json` properly because of the "." I had similar problem at mapping this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/somestuff/{fileName:.+}"
```

i had to put `:.+` so spring can properly map the url.

spring seems to truncate ".something" in this case. I actually don't know if it's the case on regular mapping, without `@PathVariable`. But you could try to map your URL without the dot and check if it will help

And that's why spring try to call the `{equipId}` function, that is waiting for PUT request. That's why in the response header you see : `allow:PUT`

Comment: Changed to "/datatable/json", however, still not mapped.